# How to send response which got from server to the email?

Tags: android, android-studio, forgot-password

I got my forgotten password from API. I want to send that password to the email address. I tried many options but still, I was unable to send that password.

Comment: Must be done from server side . If you want to do in client side best option is to launch a email intent , In that case you are not in control of the email-id and user may ignore to send . Not recommended at all from client side .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is from your backend using SMTP headers it's more secure and efficient because it's sensitive data... Never let your client-side know about this kind of data type. You can do this using bash by following [this](https://linuxhint.com/bash_script_send_email/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

We can send emails with [this tutorial](https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground)

```
BackgroundMail.newBuilder(this)
                .withUsername(from - emailid)
                .withPassword(from - emailid password)
                .withMailto(to - emailid)
                .withType(BackgroundMail.TYPE_PLAIN)
                .withSubject("Subject")
                .withSendingMessageSuccess("email sent successfully")
                .withBody("Body")
                .withOnSuccessCallback(new BackgroundMail.OnSuccessCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .withOnFailCallback(new BackgroundMail.OnFailCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFail() {
                    }
                })
                .send();
```